# SwiftUi: remove "Back" button from a detail view in WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, swiftui

Is there a way to remove the "Back" button from a detail view in WatchKit if the view has been pushed by a NavigationLink?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`?

PS: the modifier should be set inside of the detail view's body property to make it work and not on NavigationLink itself.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/3337140-navigationbarbackbuttonhidden

Comment: Thanks, missed that one